# I want to sync my music folder, Ubuntu One says it will sync once I subscribe. I just bought 20 gigs and it is still not syncying?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, music

I want to sync my music folder, Ubuntu One says it will sync once I subscribe.  I just bought 20 gigs and it is still not syncing!   What gives? I paid but nothing is happening, please don't tell me i am required to purchase the streaming music option just to back up my music in the music folder.

Answer (score 1):

I think the wording might be confusing you. You can select a folder for synchronization on one machine, but it's not automatically synchronized across all machines unless you “subscribe” each additional machine to that sync'ed folder.

Not sure if I'm making it clearer or not, here.